# How do websites like youtube/twitter make a webpage for every post?

Tags: web-development-server

How does youtube create a new web page for every video/channel?
[image: image of youtube link to video]
I want to add something to my website where users can view each others profiles however I have no idea where to start. I know there's most likely documentation for this out there but I don't know the wording.

Comment: Can you post some additional information about your development stack? What are you using for your server, frontend etc?

Comment: their endpoint /watch takes in parameters, in this case v= and t=; with this information they can check database for the data associated to the video Id and the time marker is to start at a certain chunk of the source. How they create these links for instance is when a video is uploaded, they generate a unique Id for this video along with its detail in database for future queries to access this detail. The video itself would be stored on CDN servers and DB will reference it.